# jQuery how to catch nested value in tbody?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to get the value of a nested value in a `tbody`. Here's an example that shows what I mean.

In the example I want to get all the values which are stored in the `href`.

```
<table id="toc" class="plainlinks" style="text-align: center" align="center">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Index</b></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>
          <a class="external text" href="//nl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categorie:Zelfstandig-naamwoordsvorm_in_het_Nederlands&amp;from=A">A</a>
          - <a class="external text" href="//nl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categorie:Zelfstandig-naamwoordsvorm_in_het_Nederlands&amp;from=Ab">Ab</a>
          - <a class="external text" href="//nl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categorie:Zelfstandig-naamwoordsvorm_in_het_Nederlands&amp;from=Ad">Ad</a>
          - <a class="external text" href="//nl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categorie:Zelfstandig-naamwoordsvorm_in_het_Nederlands&amp;from=Ag">Ag</a>
          - <a class="external text" href="//nl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categorie:Zelfstandig-naamwoordsvorm_in_het_Nederlands&amp;from=Al">Al</a>
          - <a class="external text" href="//nl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categorie:Zelfstandig-naamwoordsvorm_in_het_Nederlands&amp;from=Ap">Ap</a>
          - <a class="external text" href="//nl.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=Categorie:Zelfstandig--naamwoordsvorm_in_het_Nederlands&amp;from=Ap1">Ap1</a>
        </p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

I tried the following statements to catch the values:

```
$('table tr').each(function (index, value) {
  $('td' ,this).each(function (index, value) {
    $('p',  this).each(function (index, value) {
      $('a',this).each(function (index, value) {
        console.info($(this).html())
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: So is it not doing what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('table tbody a').each(function(i,el){
console.info($(el).attr('href'));
})
```

Will take all "a" in "tbody"

Answer (score 0):

**A javascript approach**

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll('table td a'),function(rm){console.log(rm.href)})
```